# Como hacer un Menú Expansible en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, activity

Tengo un requerimiento que no tengo la menor idea como hacerlo, la cuestión es: una activity que debe poseer un menú desplegable o mejor dicho expansible que se encuentre en la parte inferior como sticky, y que se pueda expandir con el gesto de arrastrar hacia arriba. De igual forma que está en la app de Google maps.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si notan el layout que tiene el texto "Antes de salir...", se despliega arrastrando hacia arriba e igualmente se cierra bajándolo.

Comment: a eso se le llama bottom sheet